# "A typical function is morse"

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, morse-theory

On the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory) for Morse theory it states the following

> A smooth real-valued function on a manifold M is a Morse function if it has no degenerate critical points.  A basic result of Morse theory says that almost all functions are Morse functions. Technically, the Morse functions form an open, dense subset of all smooth functions M → R in the C2 topology. This is sometimes expressed as "a typical function is Morse" or "a generic function is Morse".

however no reference is given. After searching for a bit I cannot find this basic result in any papers on Morse Theory. Can anyone provide a reference for this statement?

Comment: This is proved in Hirsch's book Differential Topology.

Comment: You can also check Guillemin and Pollack.

Comment: You can also check Milnor h corobodisim theorem