# Understanding the statement "almost all functions are morse"

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, differential-topology, morse-theory

Following up on my [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499928/a-typical-function-is-morse), some folks were kind enough to direct me to this theorem from 
Guillemin and Pollack, Differential Topology, Chapter 1.7

> If $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open, $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^2$ function, then for almost all $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the function $$ f_a(x) = f(x) + x \cdot a $$
>   is a Morse function.

However, I had understood the original statement I was asking about from the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory)

> A smooth real-valued function on a manifold M is a Morse function if it has no degenerate critical points.  A basic result of Morse theory says that almost all functions are Morse functions. Technically, the Morse functions form an open, dense subset of all smooth functions M → R in the C2 topology. This is sometimes expressed as "a typical function is Morse" or "a generic function is Morse".

to mean that with respect to some measure $\mu$ on $C^2$, if $F\subseteq C^2$ is the set of non-Morse functions (those with degenerate critical points), then 
$$ \mu(F) = 0$$

Could someone clarify in what sense the statement "almost all" is meant?

Comment: Given a measure over a space there are typically  non-empty sets that have "measure" 0.  For example the set of rational numbers, as a subset of the real numbers with the usual measure, has measure 0.  Saying that a property is true for 'almost all' members of a set means it is true for every member except a set of measure 0.

Comment: Guillemin and Pollack do not deal with function space topologies. They are, however, applying Sard's Theorem to conclude that the function $f_a$ will be Morse for all $a\in\Bbb R^n$ except a set of measure zero. However, by choosing $a$ very small, you will make $f_a$ as close as you want in the $C^1$ topology and $a$ has no effect on the second derivative.

Comment: @TedShifrin I understand that since the morse functions are dense, I can approximate any function with morse functions. It has been suggested to me that almost all instead refers to the fact that the morse functions form an open dense set (i.e the topological notion, not measure theoretic). I think that may be where my confusion stems from.

Comment: I made the point precisely that the "almost all" application of Sard's Theorem *does* give you the density part in the $C^2$ topology. Openness is a separate argument (although that too is sketched in the exercises in Guillemin and Pollack, if I recall correctly).